# YUM: error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: yum, centos-8

i'm trying to get yum update to work again, however, it always gives me this message, what can i do?

```
[root@CJL01 ~]# sudo yum update
Docker CE Stable - x86_64                                                                                                                                     0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'docker-ce-stable':
  - Curl error (77): Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) for https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/8/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml [error setting certificate verify lo
cations:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'docker-ce-stable': Cannot download repomd.xml: Curl error (77): Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) for https://download.docker.c
om/linux/centos/8/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml [error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none]
```

Comment: Try `sudo yum reinstall ca-certificates`, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74138675/curl-error-77-problem-with-the-ssl-ca-cert-path-access-rights-cafile-et). More ideas to be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987091/ssl-ca-cert-path-access-rights). Let me know if one worked for you.

Comment: @harrymc still same output as in the post